# Append multiple arrays to a hash in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, append

I'm trying to create an array of members who have registered for an event, but rather than creating an a array of multiple hashes, the code only stores the last member to be registered into the hash. I can't seem to figure out why.

```
total = 0
def registration
  members = []
  event = {}
  puts "First Name: ";            members << gets.chomp
  puts "Last Name: ";             members << gets.chomp
  puts "Date of Birth: ";         members << gets.chomp
  puts "Number of Events(1-4): "; members << gets.chomp.to_i
  total = '%.2f' % [(members[3] * 35.00)]
  puts "TOTAL DUE:  $#{total}"
  event = {
    :first_name => members[0],
    :last_name => members[1],
    :dob => members[2],
    :events => members[3],
    :paid => total
  }
  puts "Would you like to register another student?"
  answer = gets.chomp.downcase
  if answer == "yes"
    registration
  elsif answer == "no"
    puts "Thank you for registering.  We look forward to seeing you at the event."
    p event
  else
    puts "Please enter 'yes' or 'no'."
  end
end
registration
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This right here:

```
event = {:first_name => members[0],
         :last_name => members[1],
         :dob => members[2],
         :events => members[3],
         :paid => total}
```

is going to re-assign the hash each time you iterate.

What you want to do is add a new key / value pair to the hash instead. It's up to you to determine the key you want to use (possibly members full name?):

```
event[:member_name] => {...}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but do you mean setting 'event[:member_name]' as a key in the 'event' hash?  i.e. 'event = {event[:member_name] => members[0], etc...'?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is hinted at above.  In your comments you indicate that you are trying to 'create an array of hashes' but there is nothing in your code that puts the 'event' hash into an array.  You simply build up 'event' and then overwrite it each time you run through the code.  Presumably the result is to always return a hash with the last registration.